# Return values under same column in SPARQL query

Tags: sparql, rdf

Given three possible objects for triples, `foaf:name`, `foaf:givenName`, and `foaf:familyName`, where statements either have `foaf:name` *or* `foaf:givenName` + `foaf:familyName`, e.g.:

```
<uri1> <foaf:name> "Lolly Loozles" .

<uri2> <foaf:givenName> "Stotly" .
<uri2> <foaf:familyName> "Styles" .
```

wondering how to write a SPARQL query to return a new variable like `pretty_name` that is either the value of `foaf:name` or a concatenation of the values from `foaf:givenName` and `foaf:familyName`.

Resulting in something like:

```
?o     | ?pretty_name
----------------------
<uri1> | Lolly Loozles
<uri2> | Stotly Styles
```

This is what I have so far, but unsure how to proceed:

```
PREFIX : <https://example.org/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

# select two variables, not ideal...
SELECT ?foaf_fullName ?pretty_name

WHERE {    

    # Find all triples
    ?s ?p ?o .

    # Binds
    OPTIONAL { ?s foaf:name ?foaf_fullName }
    OPTIONAL { ?s foaf:givenName ?givenName }
    OPTIONAL { ?s foaf:familyName ?familyName }

    # Filter where predicate is part of list
    FILTER (?p IN (foaf:name, foaf:givenName, foaf:familyName ) )

    # Binds
    BIND( CONCAT(?givenName, ' ', ?familyName) AS ?pretty_name ) .

}
```

I had imagined, and tried, adding another `BIND` to add to `?pretty_name`, but the SPARQL engine wouldn't have it:

```
BIND( ?foaf_fullName AS ?pretty_name ) .
```

I also had luck writing a `CONSTRUCT` statement to get the values I'm looking for, but don't have the ability to write back to this triplestore (for a number of reasons):

```
CONSTRUCT { 
    ?s :hasPrettyName ?foaf_fullName .
    ?s :hasPrettyName ?pretty_name .
}
```

I had thought that `CONSTRUCT` could accompany `SELECT`, but must have been mistaken?

Any insight or suggestions would much appreciated.

Comment: `BIND( COALESCE(?foaf_fullName, CONCAT(?givenName, ' ', ?familyName)) AS ?pretty_name )` or `BIND( IF(BOUND(?foaf_fullName), ?foaf_fullName, CONCAT(?givenName, ' ', ?familyName)) AS ?pretty_name )`.

Comment: yeah, `coalesce` more compact vs `if` more intuitive for non experts

Comment: `COALESCE`, bingo.  That's the winner!  Thanks so much @StanislavKralin (and comments @AKSW).

Comment: An alternative, useful in some contexts, would be to build a UNION of solutions from `?fullname` and from first+family name (both bound to `?pretty_name`). In your case you would get too many results if some resources provided both `?fullname` and the components.

Answer (score 1):

Using @StanislavKralin comment/suggestion to use `COALESCE` without `IF` clauses works great:

```
PREFIX : <https://example.org/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

# select two variables, not ideal...
SELECT ?foaf_fullName ?pretty_name

WHERE {    

    # Find all triples
    ?s ?p ?o .

    # Binds
    OPTIONAL { ?s foaf:name ?foaf_fullName }
    OPTIONAL { ?s foaf:givenName ?givenName }
    OPTIONAL { ?s foaf:familyName ?familyName }

    # Filter where predicate is part of list
    FILTER (?p IN (foaf:name, foaf:givenName, foaf:familyName ) )

    # Binds
    BIND( COALESCE(?foaf_fullName, CONCAT(?givenName, ' ', ?familyName)) AS ?pretty_name )

}
```